# Calling Linux's "mailx" through java code: message-text always goes into attachment

Tags: java, linux, email, mailx

Since my SMTP provider has limit on number of emails that can be sent in  a day, I wrote a Java code to call the "mailx" of Linux system, my java-program is running on.

Here is that code:

```
package sys.cmd;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IntermediateJavaLinuxMailX {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
        email(
                new ArrayList<String>(){{
                    add("myemailid@myserver.com");
                    add("myothermailid@otherserver.com");
                }},
                "Error Message",
                "Hello World!\r\n This is message"
        );
    }

    public static void email(
            List<String>toEmailIds,
            String subject,
            String msgText
            ) throws IOException{
        String toEmails = toString(toEmailIds);
        String[]args=new String[]{"/bin/sh" , "-c", "mailx -s \""+subject+"\" "+toEmails};
        System.out.println("The command for bash is: "+args[2]);
        Process proc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
        OutputStream o = proc.getOutputStream();//probable output for text
        InputStream i = new ByteArrayInputStream(msgText.getBytes());//probable input for message-text
        read2end(i, o);
        o.close();
    }

    private static String toString(List<String> toEmailIds) {
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        for(String toEmailId:toEmailIds){
            sb.append(toEmailId).append(' ');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void read2end(InputStream i, OutputStream o) throws IOException {
        byte[]b=new byte[1000];
        for(int a=0;(a=i.read(b))>-1;)
            o.write(b, 0, a);
        i.close();
    }

}
```

The problem is: The email received on the recipients side, the text is not in the message-body, but it is in an attachment-file named "noname".

The question is: How can I make the string in `msgText` appear in email's message-body.

---

Adding one more thing I did so far:

---

I wrote another code, that uses temporary files for storing message-text & then uses file-redirection (`<`) for adding message-text & it gives desired result. But that is an indirect way. Is there any direct-way? Here is that another code:

```
    public static void email(
            List<String>toEmailIds,
            List<String>ccEmailIds,
            List<String>bccEmailIds,
            String subject,
            byte[][]attachContents,
            String messageText
            ) throws IOException{
        String toEmails=toString(" " , toEmailIds,' ');
        String ccEmails=notEmpty(ccEmailIds)?toString(" -c ", ccEmailIds,','):"";
        String bcEmails=notEmpty(bccEmailIds)?toString(" -b ", bccEmailIds,','):"";
        String recip=bcEmails+ccEmails+toEmails;
        String[]attachmentTempFiles=new String[notEmpty(attachContents)?attachContents.length:0];
        String attachFilePaths="";
        for(int x = 0;x<attachmentTempFiles.length;++x){
            String attachTempPath = "/path/temp/attach_"+x+".file";
            byteArray2File(attachContents[x],attachTempPath);
            attachmentTempFiles[x]=" -a "+attachTempPath;
            attachFilePaths+=attachmentTempFiles[x];
        }
        String msgTxtTempFilePath="/path/temp/msg.txt";
        byteArray2File(messageText.getBytes(), msgTxtTempFilePath);
        msgTxtTempFilePath=" < "+msgTxtTempFilePath;
        String mailxCommand = "mailx " + attachFilePaths + " -s \"" + subject +"\" "+ recip + msgTxtTempFilePath;
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh" , "-c", mailxCommand});
    }

    private static void byteArray2File(byte[] bs, String path) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(path);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(bs);
        read2end(bais, fos);
        fos.close();
    }

    private static boolean notEmpty(byte[][] bs) {
        return bs!=null && bs.length>0;
    }

    private static boolean notEmpty(List<String> strings) {
        return strings!=null && !strings.isEmpty();
    }

    private static String toString(String pre, List<String> toEmailIds,char separator) {
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder(pre);
        for(String toEmailId:toEmailIds){
            sb.append(toEmailId).append(separator);
        }
        return sb.substring(0,sb.length()-1);
    }

    private static void read2end(InputStream i, OutputStream o) throws IOException {
        byte[]b=new byte[1000];
        for(int a=0;(a=i.read(b))>-1;)
            o.write(b, 0, a);
        i.close();
    }
```

---

**--Edit-- Added after @Serge Ballesta's comment:**

"Hmm, I tried googling around and found Plain text file pipelined to Linux mailx turns to "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" (an attachment). Could your problem be the same ? To be sure could you control the headers of the received messages ?"

---

This code too had same effect:

```
        email(
                new ArrayList<String>(){{add("user_abc@mail1.com");add("person-xyz@mailer2.com");}},
                "Error Message",
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\r\n" +
                "Content-Disposition: inline\r\n\r\n" +
                "Hello World!\r\n" +
                "This is message.\r\n\r\n\r\n"
        );
```

Still, all the message text goes into an attachment named "noname".

Comment: Did you try to write a single dot at and of message like you would have done if using mailx directly ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I will try it just now and write the result here ASAP.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I got same results. no change.

Comment: Sorry for first stupid attempt. I put a dump program in `args` and got confirmation : what is written to pipe is correct : no null character, first line is terminated with `\n` second has no end of line.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your symptoms by giving different output to my BSD mailx but never succeeded.

Comment: Hmm, I tried googling around and found [Plain text file pipelined to Linux mailx turns to "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" (an attachment)](http://ask.fclose.com/305/plain-pipelined-content-application-octet-stream-attachment). Could your problem be the same ? To be sure could you control the headers of the received messages ?

Comment: I've just seen your last edit. The proposed work around of giving Headers in the message does not work. I'm sure there are solutions to the problem but I really need the Headers of a *received* message (the best would be full source text). And what is exactly your `mailx` version ? Not sure without received headers, but it seems that BSD version does not do exactly the same.

Comment: My mailx version is: 12.4 7/29/08. My Linux version is: Linux 2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64 x86_64

Comment: I find a heirloom mailx ... and finally reproduce problem ! Your last test has no effect because the lines `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\r\nContent-Disposition: inline` go in body and not in headers. But in the version I found removing all `\r` fixed the problem. Could you give it a try ?

Comment: I will remove `\r` and post result here.

Comment: After removing \r the whole string `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\nContent-Disposition: inline\n\nHello World!\nThis is message.\n` went into the body of the message. So now, I pass only "Hello World\!\nThis is message.\n" into the `mstText` & I can see it in message-body. Thanks for taking time & helping.

Comment: @SergeBallesta can you please edit your answer below to add that comment about removing \r, so that I can select your answer as an accepted answer, and this question can be marked as 'solved'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT : Replaced stupid things by a correct solution

The `mailx` command found in the majority of Linux distribution is [heirloom mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html). It does much more things than the original BSD mailx and automatically encodes its input if there are any *non printable characters* in it*.

The problem here is that it consideres that the `\r` characters are non standards and so it adds the following headers to the mail :

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfert-Encoding: base64
```

and the text of the mail is effectively base 64 encoded. It is not a true attachement, but many mail readers treat such mails as an empty body with an unnamed attached file.

So the solution is to remove all the `\r` from the body of the mail.

In fact, if your `LANG` environment variable declares a locale that can use non 7 bits chars (éèûôüö ...) mailx seems to be clever enough to declare an extended charset (ISO-8859-1 for fr locale) and to do quoted-printable encoding. So even with (at least west european) non 7bits ASCII characters in the message, provided there are no control chararacters, the mail should be sent normally.

The last chance solution would be not to use mailx and directly use sendmail.

Comment: both the solutions given by you had no effect on the output.