# Unix mail automatically sending my message as an attachment

Tags: email, unix

I have a mail command that looks something like this:

```
sh ~/filter.sh ~/build/site_build.err | mail -s "Site updated." me\@site.com
```

The bash script has a few commands, mostly grep, to filter the stderr. It sends the filtered content to me when our build process has finished.

It used to send the file contents in the message body, however now it's sending as an attachment, which I do not want.

When I delete most of the text it sends to me in the message body once again, so I've reasoned that this has to do with the message size -- is this correct?

Anyway, how can I prevent Unix from sending the message contents as an attachment, no matter the circumstances?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still unsure as many things could cause `mail` to apparently send input as attachement. But in many Linux distribution, `mail` is an alias for  is [heirloom mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html). It is known to encode its input if there are any non printable characters in it.

As soon as it finds non standards characters, it adds the following headers to the mail :

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfert-Encoding: base64
```

and the text of the mail is effectively base 64 encoded. It is not a true attachement, but many mail readers treat such mails as an empty body with an unnamed attached file.

If your LANG environment variable declares a locale that can use non 7 bits chars (éèûôüö ...) mail seems to be clever enough to declare an extended charset (ISO-8859-1 for fr locale) and to do quoted-printable encoding. So even with (at least west european) non 7bits ASCII characters in the message, provided there are no control chararacters, the mail should be sent normally.

The alternative would be to filter all non printable characters from the output of `filter.sh`, and the last chance solution would be not to use mail and directly use sendmail.

(Ref : an [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252434/3545273) to an other post but that one concerned java)

Comment: I think this is the answer that I needed. I'll need to check the character set that gets printed but will assume that this gets at the issue.